# Error in configuring custom directory for webserver - apachectl

Tags: php, apache

I am new and currently learning php and apache. I followed a tutorial on how to connect apache and php on Mac, and I am stuck on the part where we can customize configured directory. Here's what I have added and change.

I added a new file called `YOURUSERNAME.conf` in `/etc/apache2/users/` with content as follow:

```
<Directory /Users/*/Sites>
 DirectoryIndex index.html index.php index index.html default.html default.htm
 AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit Indexes
 Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
 <Limit GET POST OPTIONS>
 Require all granted
 </Limit>
 <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>
 Require all denied
 </LimitExcept>
</Directory>
```

I've also uncommented lines in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`:

```
LoadModule authn_core_module libexec/apache2/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authz_host_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
LoadModule userdir_module libexec/apache2/mod_userdir.so
```

And uncommented `Include /private/etc/apache2/users/*.conf` in `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf`

Then I have a directory `Sites` in my home directory with a file `index.php` with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`.

When I enter http://localhost/~yourusername in my browser, I got the following message: `The requested URL /~yourusername was not found on this server.`

Can someone please explain why?

Comment: A very important skill is log-files reading. There are answers on most _"why smth. doesn't work"_ questions in the `error_log` file.

Comment: Where is the `error_log` file?

Comment: Usually, in the `apache2/logs` directory. If not, look through configs for `ErrorLog` directive and there will be a path.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping. `[Tue May 26 19:20:54.488220 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 17714] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Unix) PHP/5.5.20 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue May 26 19:20:54.488282 2015] [core:notice] [pid 17714] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND' ` I don't think the ErrorLog file is showing any errors. I'm thinking the problem is that I did not set the configuration of the custom directory right.